# How to find if it's 32 or 64 bits? Tomcat

Tags: version, tomcat7

I recently downloaded Tomcat 7.x as a zip. Running the version.bat gives the following:

```
c:\apache-tomcat-7.0.19\bin>version
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.19"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "c:\apache-tomcat-7.0.19"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.19\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_29"
Using CLASSPATH:       "c:\apache-tomcat-7.0.19\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\apache-tomcat-    7.0.19\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.19
Server built:   Jul 13 2011 11:32:28
Server number:  7.0.19.0
OS Name:        Windows Server 2008 R2
OS Version:     6.1
Architecture:   x86
JVM Version:    1.6.0_29-b11
JVM Vendor:     Sun Microsystems Inc.
```

Since it's using the 32 bit version of JRE, is it a safe assumption the Tomcat itself is 32-bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows distributions contain executables and a DLL to run Tomcat as a service.  You can unzip the download & run Dependency Walker (free) or dumpbin.exe (comes with MS Visual Studio) on the executable to see which processor architecture they support.

See this question for more details: [In windows,how do we identify whether a file is 64 bit or 32 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023295/in-windows-how-do-we-identify-whether-a-file-is-64-bit-or-32-bit)

Java programs aren't 32-bit or 64-bit as native programs are.  They run in a virtual machine with a standard architecture.  Only the JRE, which implements the virtual machine, is 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: I totally understand this point. However, the root of my question lies in the fact that there are two separate Tomcat downloads, one for 32 bits and the other for 64 bits Windows.

Comment: doubt this answer, since found many java application like eclipse have different executable 32-bit and 64-bit

Comment: Java class files distributed in Jar files, the most common distribution method for Java programs, are portable to any system with a JRE, whether 32-bit or 64-bit.  Native executables that launch Java programs using JNI, such as Tomcat or Eclipse, are indeed specific to 32-bit or 64-bit systems.  Java programs compiled to native executables by GCJ or other compilers are system-specific as well.

Answer (score 2):

In the Tomcat bin folder, there is version.bat (version.sh for linux) script. Run it to get version and architecture information.  Here is example output for Tomcat 7.062 running 32 bit (x86) on Windows:

```
C:\KBData\Software\apache-tomcat-7.0.62\bin>version
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\KBData\Software\apache-tomcat-7.0.62"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\KBData\Software\apache-tomcat-7.0.62"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\KBData\Software\apache-tomcat-7.0.62\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\KBData\Software\apache-tomcat-7.0.62\bin\bootstrap.ja
r;C:\KBData\Software\apache-tomcat-7.0.62\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.62
Server built:   May 7 2015 17:14:55 UTC
Server number:  7.0.62.0
OS Name:        Windows 7
OS Version:     6.1
Architecture:   x86
JVM Version:    1.7.0_25-b17
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```